# Remove extra white space bellow and above product short description in storefront woocommerce

Tags: css

Please help me to remove extra white space below and above the product short description in the storefront theme.

I am a novice. Here is the link to my website [enter link description here](https://staging.saosis.com/shop/buy-organic-soil-fertilizer-organic-npk-fertilizer-slow-release-soil-fertilizer-organic-fertilizer-mix-garden-soil-fertilizer)